# Issues including Fibaro's FGS-223

Tags: smart-home, zwave, home-assistant, openhab

I'm struggling with my fgs-223, the device does not include or exclude, the only thing I succeeded is to hard reset it.

This is a video of my trials, please tell me if anything is done wrong: https://www.dropbox.com/s/w4qz546igt3hya7/20190409_084413.mp4

I'm trying different clicking speeds (you can hear it in the video) with no real feedback from the z-stick, you can also see I'm toggling the S1 from open to close and retrying the 3-click scenario a bunch of time.

BTW I'm using a gen5 aeotec z-stick and the fgs223 was hard reset before the video recording.

Comment: you  are not clicking S1